# Is it possible to use a Mac code-signing certificate to sign for Windows and Linux? Which standard does it implement?

Tags: macos, certificate

I need to sign a few executables. I already have a Mac certificate. Is there a way to use this to sign for Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 1):

There is not. Windows does not trust the Mac CA, so you can't effectively reuse a Mac certificate.